# Can't control Wordpress Addresses from admin panel

Tags: wordpress

Good Morning,

I have already created several sites in WordPress and I have always been able to manage the link of my site with or without https and with or without www through the settings in options > general, as you can see here: https://prnt.sc/lzv62u

Lately, I have to use a plugin to force https and I've even added code to the htaccess file to redirect to "non-www". However, this htaccess file loses those changes that I make very often (I do not know why).

I would like to know, first of all, if it is possible to manage this type of settings again through the admin panel of my WordPress. If it is not possible, I would like to know why and what is different for this particular site cannot control these settings in the admin panel (because I have already managed to do so in others).

Secondly, if this is not possible, I would like a permanent solution to redirect from www.floresnocais.pt to floresnocais.pt since I already have a plugin to force https.

Thank you

Comment: This would be better being asked on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic about the types of questions you can ask

Answer (score 1):

Set the .htaccess rights to 400 after applying all the required changes to the file. This will make the file read-only and prevent any further changes.

We faced the same issue in the past while using the  WPML and the events manager plugin. There were issues in preserving the permalinks. The issue may be due to multiple plugins have the write access to .htaccess file and one is overwriting changes of the another.